# Conditions based on days per groups

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

```
            A                   B       C   D   E
0  2002-01-12 2018-04-25 10:00:00    John  19  19
1  2002-01-12 2018-04-25 11:00:00    John   6  25
2  2002-01-13 2018-04-25 09:00:00    John   5  30
3  2002-01-13 2018-04-25 11:00:00    John -25   5
4  2002-01-14 2018-04-25 11:00:00    John   1   6
5  2002-01-14 2018-04-25 12:00:00    John  44  50
6  2002-01-25 2018-04-25 11:00:00  George  18  18
7  2002-01-25 2018-04-25 12:00:00  George  12  30
8  2002-01-26 2018-04-25 11:00:00  George  -8  22
9  2002-01-26 2018-04-25 12:00:00  George -10  12
10 2002-01-27 2018-04-25 10:00:00  George  13  25
11 2002-01-27 2018-04-25 11:00:00  George   1  26

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df["E"] = df.groupby("C")["D"].cumsum()
```

I want to select one row per each `C` group, with next conditions:

- Take first row where `E>=20` and `B==11:00:00`, apply just from second `A` day of each `C` group.
- If it doesn´t exist any row which satisfies that condition, take first row of that `C` group.

Output should be:

```
            A                   B       C   D   E
0  2002-01-12 2018-04-25 10:00:00    John  19  19
8  2002-01-26 2018-04-25 11:00:00  George  -8  22
```

I´ve tried:

```
def eleven(g):
    cond = g[g.B==time(11)].E.ge(20)
    if cond.any():
        return g[cond].iloc[0]
    else:
        return g.iloc[1]

r = df.groupby('C', as_index=False).apply(eleven)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need change condition with chain condition for compare `E` and for second group by `A` use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html), for second group use `>0`:

```
def eleven(g):
    cond = (g.B.dt.hour==11) & (g.E.ge(20) & pd.factorize(g.A)[0]) > 0
    if cond.any():
        return g[cond].iloc[0]
    else:
        return g.iloc[0]

r = df.groupby('C', as_index=False, sort=False).apply(eleven)
print (r)
           A                   B       C   D   E
0 2002-01-12 2018-04-25 10:00:00    John  19  19
1 2002-01-26 2018-04-25 11:00:00  George  -8  22
```

Comment: But this output doesn´t satisfy first condition: "Take first row where `E>=20` and `B==11:00:00`, apply just from second A day of each C group." `0 2002-01-12 2018-04-25 11:00:00    John  6  25
` belongs to the first `A` day of `C` group.

Comment: @Tie_24 - just realised it.

Comment: It works perfect! I didn´t know `factorize` function. Thank you very much jezrael !!

Comment: @Tie_24 - Glad can help!